# Element Click Intercepted Exception in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, testing

I want to perform a simple test case with selenium in Visual Studio(C#). For this reason, I wrote a short code to click on the variables of a random website, I accessed the buttons with the id, class or xpath, but I get an error like this -> openQA.selenium.Element.Click.Intercepted

If the narration is insufficient, I can add the codes.

Comment: Depends on the button and how you click it. Please add code snippets from your button template (and sourroundings if needed) and from your selenium method clicking the button. Also take a read [here](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2020/05/25/elementclickinterceptedexception-element-click-intercepted-not-clickable-at-point-other-element-would-receive-the-click/). Its an article explaining why some buttons might not be clickable and how you can manage it in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use javascriptexecutor this situation.
For example,

```
WebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return document.title");
```